# $H$ char $K$ and $K$ char $G$ then $H$ char $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $H \leq G$ and $K \leq G$

Prove that $H$ is characteristic in $K$ and $K$ is characteristic in $G$ then $H$ characteristic in $G$

$H$ char $K$ $\Rightarrow$ $\forall \sigma \in Aut(K)$, $\sigma(H)=H$. $\forall k \in K , kHk^{-1}=H$

$K$ char $G$ $\Rightarrow$ $\forall \sigma \in Aut(G)$, $\sigma(K)=K$. $\forall g \in G , gKg^{-1}=K$

this is what I know. but I do not know how would i deduce that $H$ characteristic in $G$ . Would someone help me out with that. Thank you

Comment: Hint : if $\sigma\in Aut(G)$, then to prove that $\sigma(H)=H$ you can prove that $\sigma_{|K}\in Aut(K)$.

Answer (score 4):

If $\sigma\in\text{Aut}(G)$ then $\sigma(K)=K$ because $K\text{ char }G$, so in particular $\sigma$ restricts to an automorphism of $K$. You can now use this to see that $\sigma(H)=H$.

Comment: I am sorry you basically rewrite what I had. Would you explain a bit more for me. Thank you

Comment: @ADAM Since $K$ is characteristic, $\sigma(K)\subseteq K$. On the other hand, also $\sigma^{-1}$ is an automorphism of $G$, so $\sigma^{-1}(K)\subseteq K$, which implies $K\subseteq \sigma(K)$. Therefore $\sigma(K)=K$. Hence $\sigma$ induces an automorphism of $K$, so that $\sigma(H)=H$ as $H$ is characteristic in $K$.